# Concatenação de listas em haskell eliminando as repetições

Tags: lista, haskell

Olá, já faz algumas horinhas que estou tentando  fazer uma função em haskell que dê duas listas e retorna uma nova lista

Onde esta nova lista é a união das outras duas listas mas sem repetições ,ou seja, uma lista **[1,2,3][3,2,1]** deveria retornar **[1,2,3]**  ou uma lista **[10,20,30][90,80,30]** deveria retornar **[10,20,30,90,80]** **(veja que o 30 está nas duas listas, logo não deve estar na lista)**

O que eu tenho é isto :

```
uniaoS :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]

uniaoS [] [] =[]

uniaoS [] (x:xs) =(x:xs)

uniaoS (x:xs) [] =(x:xs)

uniaoS(a:as)(x:xs) 

| (a == x) = uniaoS as xs 

| otherwise = a:as ++ x:xs
```

Neste caso ele está retornando a lista menos as repetições , ou seja **[1,2,3] [1,2,4]** retorna **[3,4]**, mas eu gostaria que também retornasse os elementos repetidos [**1,2**,*3,4]*

Answer (score 3):

Comecemos por tentar perceber porque é que a sua função `uniaoS` retorna `[3, 4]` e não `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Usando o seu exemplo, os dados de entrada são as listas `[1,2,3]` e `[1,2,4]` e a definição da função é

```
uniaoS(a:as)(x:xs) 
    | (a == x) = uniaoS as xs 
    | otherwise = a:as ++ x:xs
```

À entrada da função, `a = 1` e `x = 1`, logo caimos no caso `(a == x) = uniaoS as xs`. O que acontece aqui é que simplesmente descarta o `a` e o `x` e avalia recursivamente as duas listas até encontrar um caso em que `a` seja diferente de `x`.

Sabendo isto, deixo aqui uma sugestão (não a resposta completa) para resolução. Normalmente um boa forma de resolver um problema é dividi-lo em partes. Neste caso o seu problema pode ser dividido em:

1. Concatenar duas listas
2. Remover os elementos duplicados

Assumindo que tem uma função que remove duplicados de uma lista e que esta função tem a seguinte assinatura `f :: [Int] -> [Int]`, então a unica coisa que precisa é de concatenar as duas listas antes de aplicar `f`. Em Haskell isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
concatenarListas:: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
concatenarListas xs ys = f (xs ++ ys)
```

A única coisa que fica a faltar é a definição da função `f`.

Caso não consiga chegar a uma definição para f avise que eu actualizo a resposta.

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado bruno, consegui que funcionasse, mais tarde postarei o código

Answer (score 0):

O problema que encontrei no teu código foi que estás comparar apenas elementos que estão na cabeça das listas, logo, isso não resolve quando os elementos encontar-se em posições diferentes.

A lógica que aconselho utilizares é, comparar um único elemento de qualquer lista com todos os elementos da outra lista.

para isso eu criarei duas funções.

A primeira função recebe uma lista e um número inteiro, retorna False caso o número não pertencer na lista e True caso o número pertencer na lista, a função é esta:

```
 func1 :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool
 func1 [] n = False
 func1 (x:xs) n = if n == x then True else func1 xs n
```

A segunda função recebe duas listas e retorna uma lista que é a união das duas lista, para isso vou usar a primeira função que recebe a primeira lista e o primeiro elemento da segunda lista, e faz comparação com todos elementos da segunda lista.
Nessa segunda função utilizarei recursão para comparar todos elementos da primeira lista com os elementos da segunda lista e fica desse jeito:

```
func2 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
func2 lst1 [] = lst1
func2 lst1 (x:xs) = if func1 lst1 x then func2 lst1 xs else func2 lst1 xs [x]
```

Nota: Apenas retorna as duas listas unidas e não faz ordenação.